# Filtering an ObservableCollection Based on CheckBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` that contains a number of `Jobs`. Each of these `Jobs` has an employee associated with it, and I would like to filter based on which Employees are on those jobs. So I have four `CheckBoxes`;

```
<CheckBox x:Name="employeeARad" Content="EmployeeA" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Margin="7,0,0,5"/>
<CheckBox x:Name="employeeBRad" Content="EmployeeD" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Margin="7,5,0,5"/>
<CheckBox x:Name="employeeCRad" Content="EmployeeC" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,5,0,5" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18"/>
<CheckBox x:Name="employeeDRad" Content="EmployeeD" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,5,0,5" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18"/>
```

I retrieve and fill an `ObservableCollection` of data from my Database. I then bind this collection to my `DataGrid` using: `dataGrid.ItemsSource = _jobDataService.GetJobList();`. As I stated before, each job has part of its model associated with an `Employee`. Here is the model for a `Job`;

```
class JobModel
{
    public int CaseNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string CaseNotes { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateDeadline { get; set; }
    public string CaseClient { get; set; }
}
```

My question really is how can I filter this collection that is bound to the `DataGrid` based upon the selection of `CheckBoxes`?

Comment: If you need filtering it's better to use ListCollectionView. var lcv = new ListCollectionView(yourObservableCollection); yourDataGrid.ItemsSource=lcv;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you bind to a collection in WPF, an object that derives from `ICollectionView` is created behind-the-scenes. This interface supports sorting and filtering of the collection through the use of various properties.

What I typically do is have an `ObservableCollection<T>` assigned to a private field, which holds all of the data. Then I have a corresponding public property of type `ICollectionView`, to which I apply any sorting or filtering criteria.

The following is the XAML for a simple window that contains a list of jobs, plus check boxes to filter the list by employee name. To keep things simple I'm showing *only* the employee name in the list of jobs:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <DockPanel Margin="10">
        <StackPanel x:Name="_employees" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <CheckBox Content="Fred" IsChecked="True" Click="OnCheckBoxClick" />
            <CheckBox Content="Wilma" IsChecked="True" Click="OnCheckBoxClick" />
            <CheckBox Content="Barney" IsChecked="True" Click="OnCheckBoxClick" />
            <CheckBox Content="Betty" IsChecked="True" Click="OnCheckBoxClick" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding JobsCollectionView}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="EmployeeName" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Here's the code-behind for this window (I've reused your existing `JobModel` class, so that code isn't shown here):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _jobs = new ObservableCollection<JobModel>
            {
                new JobModel { EmployeeName = "Fred" },
                new JobModel { EmployeeName = "Wilma" },
                new JobModel { EmployeeName = "Fred" },
                new JobModel { EmployeeName = "Barney" },
                new JobModel { EmployeeName = "Betty" },
            };

            JobsCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_jobs);
            DataContext = this;
        }

        readonly ObservableCollection<JobModel> _jobs;

        public ICollectionView JobsCollectionView { get; private set; }

        void OnCheckBoxClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var checkedEmployees = new HashSet<string>();
            foreach (CheckBox checkBox in _employees.Children)
            {
                if (checkBox.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    checkedEmployees.Add((string) checkBox.Content);
                }
            }

            JobsCollectionView.Filter =
                job => checkedEmployees.Contains((job as JobModel).EmployeeName);
        }
    }
}
```

You can see the private `_jobs` field which holds the collection of jobs, and the public `JobsCollectionView` property that provides access to the `ICollectionView` implementation (the `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView` method is used to obtain this).

Each **CheckBox** control has a **Click** event handler (they all point to the same method) which simply iterates through the check boxes to build a list of employee names that are currently "checked" (`checkedEmployees`), then sets the `Filter` property of the collection view to apply the appropriate filtering logic. Basically the filter is a delegate that takes an item from the view (a `JobModel` object, in your case) and returns a Boolean value that indicates whether that particular object should be included in the view. Here I'm just checking that the name of the employee from the job is contained in the set of filtered employee names.

One thing to be aware of is that performance of `ICollectionView` sorting and filtering can be an issue for very large lists, in which case you may need to sort/filter by constructing an entirely new list from your original set of data. I would try the collection view approach first however, and see how you get on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will this still work for filtering a `DataGrid` instead of  a `ListBox`?

Comment: I've not really used the `DataGrid` but I believe it derives from `ItemsControl` just like `ListBox`, so yes it should work.

Comment: Just one final passing question, say I wanted to use a `CheckBox` but not filter on its content, is there a way to do this? For example, the `CheckBox` content is 'EmployeeA' but I actually want to filter where `EmployeeName = Fred`?

Comment: The easiest way given what you already have would be to use a different property of the CheckBox to hold the name you want to filter on: `Tag` would be ideal for this. For example: `<CheckBox Content="EmployeeA" Tag="Fred" ... />`. Then in the `OnCheckBoxClick` method just reference `checkBox.Tag` instead of `checkBox.Content`.